# Tricky Integral -- $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2-4x+3} \arcsin(x)~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**TL;DR: I can't get a closed form for the integral below.**

$$ \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2-4x+3} \arcsin(x)~dx $$

---

I got an interesting question from a coworker a while ago:

> Question:
>
> The quantities $a$, $b$, and $c$ are chosen uniformly and independently from $[0, 1]$.
>
> a) What is the probability a triangle can be constructed with $a$, $b$, and $c$ as side lengths?
>
> b) Given we can form such a triangle, what is its expected area?

I can do a) pretty easily -- each constraint like $a < b + c$ cuts off a corner of the cube with area $1/6$, and the cut-off bits are disjoint, so the remaining area is $1/2$.

Part b) is where things get hairy. I can [reduce the problem](http://www.texpaste.com/n/j1koauro) down to a single integral. I feel like it should be expressible in terms of known constants, though I admit I have no good reason to believe this.

$$
\frac{3}{40} \int_0^1 x \sqrt{3-4x+x^2} \left( \sqrt{1 - x^2} + \frac{\arcsin{x}}{x} \right)~dx
$$

That can be split into two parts:

$$
\frac{3}{40} \int_0^1 x \sqrt{(3-4x+x^2)(1 - x^2)}~dx + \frac{3}{40} \int_0^1 \sqrt{3-4x+x^2} \arcsin(x)~dx
$$

The first part can be solved exactly.
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x \sqrt{(3-4x+x^2)(1 - x^2)}~dx &= \int_0^1 x \sqrt{(3-x)(1-x)(1-x)(1+x)}~dx \\
&= \int_0^1 x(1-x) \sqrt{(3-x)(1+x)}~dx \\
&= \frac{1}{12} (32 - 9 \sqrt{3} - 4\pi) \textrm{ by Mathematica}
\end{align*}
$$

The second part is still pretty stubborn.

Mathematica tells me the integral (without the 3/40 constant) is approximately 0.452854, but doesn't given an exact form. Does anyone have any ideas how to evaluate this further?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253893/probability-that-three-independent-uniform-0-1-random-variables-can-form-a-t

Comment: Yep, that's part a; I was able to do that part

Comment: I think you can just express the area using Heron's formula. Since you know the distributions of $a$, $b$ and $c$, you can find the distribution and expected value of the area.

Comment: @GReyes This was obviously already done. You can check the  expression for the final integral.

Comment: So what is the question? The textpaste link doesn't work, by the way ...

Comment: @Math-fun I guess to evaluate the, most likely, non-elementary integral. The link works at least for me.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/how-many-regular-mse-users-frequent-the-meta-page

Comment: With the help of Mathematica I found that $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2-4x+3} \arcsin(x)~dx$
conjecturally evaluates to $$-2 G+\frac{1}{2} i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{-i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+1}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+1}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-i}{(2-i)+\sqrt{3}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{(2+i)+\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)-\frac{7 \sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi }{3}+3-\frac{1}{12} \pi  \log \left(14-8 \sqrt{3}\right),$$ where G is Catalan's Constant. The hope is that this ugly expression can be simplified further.

Comment: @JamesArathoon wow, that's... intense

Comment: One other interesting result I've found includes an infinite series involving the incomplete Beta function: $$-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{-n} \binom{2 n}{n} B_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(n+1,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2^{2 n} (2 n+1)}-\frac{7 \sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi }{3}+3-\frac{1}{2} \pi \; \text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right).$$ The incomplete Beta function in the expression, as a function of $n$, evaluates to a sequence of numbers all of the form $a-b\sqrt{6}$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers.

Comment: @JamesArathoon. Beautiful result ! Which version are you using ? I tried using The Wolfram Development Platform and ... no result.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: I had to evaluate using integration by parts more than once, and when needed, manually calculate definite integrals from indefinite results to coax these results out of Mathematica 11.3.. I was really expecting a much simpler result than mine to emerge.

Comment: @JamesArathoon. This is really a good work ! I bet it has been quite tedious. Cheers & thanks :-)

Comment: @JamesArathoon That ugly expression you obtained can be tidied up quite marvelously in terms of the Clausen function as: $I=3-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{3}-2C+\frac54\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}$.

Comment: I believe your expression for the expected area of the triangle, $\frac{3}{40} \int_0^1 x \sqrt{3-4x+x^2} \left( \sqrt{1 - x^2} + \frac{\arcsin{x}}{x} \right)~dx$, is exactly half of what it should be. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4843914/398708).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

---

### WARNING: Incoming wall of math.

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the value of the definite integral,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{x^{2}-4x+3}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

For our purposes here we may define the inverse sine function of a real argument via the usual integral representation

$$\arcsin{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{-1\le z\le1}.$$

The integral definition of $\arcsin$ is particularly handy for deriving the following inverse trigonometric identity:

$$\forall z\in\left[0,1\right]:\arcsin{\left(1-2z^{2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arcsin{\left(z\right)}.$$

Similarly, the inverse hyperbolic sine function of a real argument may be defined via the integral representation

$$\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}},$$

and it can be verified through differentiation that the inverse hyperbolic sine may be expressed in the logarithmic form

$$\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(z\right)}=\ln{\left(z+\sqrt{1+z^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}}.$$

---

Turning now to the main task of evaluating $\mathcal{I}$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{x^{2}-4x+3}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{\left(3-x\right)\left(1-x\right)}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{\left(2+x\right)x}\arcsin{\left(1-x\right)};~~~\small{\left[x\mapsto1-x\right]}\\
&=4\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{x\left(1+x\right)}\arcsin{\left(1-2x\right)};~~~\small{\left[x\mapsto2x\right]}\\
&=8\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(1-2x^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x\mapsto x^{2}\right]}\\
&=8\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=4\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}\left(4+4x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}\left(3+4x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x^{3}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right]+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x^{2}+1-1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x^{2}+1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right]-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Define the auxiliary functions $f:\left[-1,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $g:\left[-1,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ via the respective expressions,

$$f{\left(x\right)}:=2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]$$

and

$$g{\left(x\right)}:=4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right].$$

We then obtain the following expression for the derivative of $f$ at $x\in\left(-1,1\right)$:

$$\begin{align}
f^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigg{[}2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right]\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\frac{2x^{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2+2x^{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}+\frac{4x^{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

In a similar fashion, we also obtain the following expression for the derivative of $g$ at $x\in\left(-1,1\right)$:

$$\begin{align}
g^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigg{[}4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right]\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\left[\left(8x\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)+4x^{2}\left(\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right)\right]\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=2x\left[6\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right]\left[\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=2x\left[6\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\\
&~~~~~+2x\left[6\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right]x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+4x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=2x\left[\frac{2\left(2+3x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right]-\frac{4x^{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}+16x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Returning to the evaluation of $\mathcal{I}$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-16\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,g^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,2x\left[\frac{2\left(2+3x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right]-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{4x^{2}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,g^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\left(4+6x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,f^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,g^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,f^{\prime}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\left(5+6x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\left[g{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-g{\left(0\right)}\right]-\left[f{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-f{\left(0\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(5+6y\right)\sqrt{1-y}}{\sqrt{1+y}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{y}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\sqrt{3}\left[1+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\sqrt{3}\left[1+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]+2\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(5+6y\right)\left(1-y\right)}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=2+\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-2\sqrt{3}\left[1+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{5+y-6y^{2}}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=2+\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-2\sqrt{3}\left[1+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}+\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{3-6y^{2}}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}+\int_{0}^{\frac12}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=2+\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-2\sqrt{3}\left[1+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-t}};~~~\small{\left[y=\sqrt{t}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}+2\arcsin{\left(\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=2+\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-2\sqrt{3}\left[1+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+1+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{3}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=3-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Let $\mathcal{J}$ denote the value of the definite integral,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}
&:=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Integrating by parts and applying a certain Euler substitution, we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\\
&=2\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{I.B.P.s}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac12}\right)}-2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(-x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{1}^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{\frac32}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(-1\right)\left(1+y^{2}\right)}{2y^{2}}\cdot\frac{\ln{\left(y\right)}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1-y^{2}}{2y}\right)^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{1+x^{2}}=x+y\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2\left(1+y^{2}\right)\ln{\left(y\right)}}{y\sqrt{4y^{2}-\left(1-y^{2}\right)^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2\left(1+y^{2}\right)\ln{\left(y\right)}}{y\sqrt{-1+6y^{2}-y^{4}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2\ln{\left(y\right)}}{y\sqrt{-1+6y^{2}-y^{4}}}+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2y^{2}\ln{\left(y\right)}}{y\sqrt{-1+6y^{2}-y^{4}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}-1}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(-t^{-2}\right)2\ln{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}}{t^{-1}\sqrt{-1+6t^{-2}-t^{-4}}};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1}{t}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\sqrt{u}\right)}}{\sqrt{-1+6u-u^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[y=\sqrt{u}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{1}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2t\ln{\left(t\right)}}{\sqrt{-t^{4}+6t^{2}-1}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(u\right)}}{2\sqrt{-1+6u-u^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{1}^{2+\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(u\right)}}{2\sqrt{-u^{2}+6u-1}};~~~\small{\left[t=\sqrt{u}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(u\right)}}{2\sqrt{-1+6u-u^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{2\sqrt{8-\left(x-3\right)^{2}}}-\int_{1}^{2+\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{2\sqrt{8-\left(x-3\right)^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}-x\right)\left(x-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{1}^{2+\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}-x\right)\left(x-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}},\\
\end{align}$$

and then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}-x\right)\left(x-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{1}^{2+\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}-x\right)\left(x-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}-2+\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}-3+2\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}-1}{1-3+2\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(-1\right)\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{y}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}-1}{1-3+2\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}-2-\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}-3+2\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left(-1\right)\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{y}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}-x}{x-3+2\sqrt{2}}=y\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{-1+\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1+2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{-1+2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{y}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{1+2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{-1+2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{-1+\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{y}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}^{\left(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{y}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\left(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}-2\right)^{2}}^{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)y}{1+y}\right)}}{\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{y}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\int_{1+\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+2}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}-2}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=t^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\int_{\tan{\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}}^{\tan{\left(\frac{11\pi}{24}\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}}{1+t^{2}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{\tan{\left(\frac{5\pi}{24}\right)}}^{\tan{\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}}{1+t^{2}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{11\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}{2}\cdot\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}{1+\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}\right)}}{1+\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{\frac{5\pi}{12}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}{2}\cdot\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}{1+\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}\right)}}{1+\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[t=\tan{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{11\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}{\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{5\pi}{12}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}{\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{11\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{5\pi}{12}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

and then after setting $\alpha:=\arcsin{\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)}\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{11\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{5\pi}{12}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{\pi}{12}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\varphi\mapsto\pi-\varphi\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{\frac{\pi}{12}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3\right)}+\frac12\int_{\frac{\pi}{12}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(3\right)}-\frac12\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\pi\ln{\left(3\right)}}{12}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{7\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\pi\ln{\left(3\right)}}{12}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{7\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

The remaining logarithmic integrals can be evaluated in terms of Clausen functions using the following integration formula, which holds for any $\left(\alpha,\vartheta\right)\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\times\mathbb{R}$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}
&=\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(2\theta+2\omega\right)}-\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(2\theta\right)}-\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(2\omega\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\theta\ln{\left(\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}-\omega\ln{\left(\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}\\
\end{align}$$

where

$$\omega:=\arctan{\left(\frac{\tan{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(\vartheta\right)}}{1-\tan{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\vartheta\right)}}\right)}\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$

Recall that the Clausen function may be defined for real arguments via the integral representation,

$$\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\theta\right)}:=-\int_{0}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(\left|2\sin{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}\right|\right)};~~~\small{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}.$$

---

Having obtained explicit expressions for each of the integrals comprising $\mathcal{J}$, a little algebraic elbow-grease yields a greatly simplified final value:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\pi\ln{\left(3\right)}}{12}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{7\pi}{12}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-\sin{\left(\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\pi\ln{\left(3\right)}}{12}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\pi\right)}-2\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{\left(\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}+\frac{\pi}{24}\ln{\left(\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}+\frac{\pi}{12}\ln{\left(\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)}+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)}+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}+\frac{7\pi}{24}\ln{\left(\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}+\frac{\pi}{12}\ln{\left(\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\pi\ln{\left(3\right)}}{12}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\pi}{12}\ln{\left(\sec^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}-\frac{\pi}{12}\ln{\left(\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)}+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}+\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}-2\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\pi\ln{\left(3\right)}}{12}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\pi}{12}\ln{\left(\frac32\right)}-\frac{\pi}{12}\ln{\left(\frac12\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)}+\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}+\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}-2\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac54\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}-2C+\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Finally(!), we arrive at our desired result:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=3-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\,\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arsinh}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-2\sqrt{3}\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\mathcal{J}\\
&=3-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{3}-2C+\frac54\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: This is amazing! My browser froze trying to scroll it down $\ddot \frown$

Comment: Christ, that's one hell of an answer! No wonder I couldn't get anywhere with this. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @HenrySwanson You're quite welcome. I apologize if my answer is a bit lacking in overall explanation. I usually like to provide more insight into how one goes about planning such a long chain of derivations ahead of time, but I was just too exhausted to go back and add those details by the time I finished calculating the integral. ^^;

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer.*

We could use
$$\sqrt{x^2-4x+3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^n$$ with
$$a_n=\frac{2(2 n-3)\, a_{n-1}-(n-3)\, a_{n-2}}{3 n} \qquad \text{where}\qquad a_0=\sqrt{3}\qquad a_1=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$ and
$$\int_0^1 x^n\arcsin(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi }{2( n+1)}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{(n+1)^2
  \,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$$ but the convergence is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

We can extract the non-Catalan/-Clausen parts with a few elementary steps:

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 3} \arcsin x \, dx \\
&= 4 \int_0^{\tfrac13} \frac{\sqrt y}{(1-y)^3} \arcsin \frac{1-3y}{1-y} dy \tag 1 \\
&= \int_0^{\tfrac13} \left(\operatorname{artanh}\sqrt y - \frac{\sqrt y(1+y)}{(1-y)^2}\right) \, \frac{dy}{(y-1) \sqrt y \sqrt{1-2y}} \tag2 \\
&= \int_0^{\tfrac13} \frac{\operatorname{artanh} \sqrt y}{\sqrt y \sqrt{1-2y} (y-1)} \, dy + \int_0^{\tfrac13} \frac{(1+y)}{(1-y)^3 \sqrt{1-2y}} \, dy \\
&= \underbrace{\int_0^{\tfrac1{\sqrt3}} \frac{\ln\frac{1-z}{1+z}}{\sqrt{1-2z^2} (1-z^2)} \, dz}_{=:J} + 4 \int_0^{\tfrac1{\sqrt3}} \frac{z^2-3}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2} \, dz \tag3 \\
&= \frac\pi3+3-\frac{7\sqrt3}4 + J
\end{align*}$$

Then we can find a closed form for $J$ in terms of polylogarithms as follows:

$$\newcommand{\dilog}[1]{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(#1\right)} \\
\begin{align*}
J &= \int_0^{\tfrac1{\sqrt3}} \frac{\ln\frac{1-z}{1+z}}{\sqrt{1-2z^2} \, \left(1-z^2\right)} \, dz \\
&= \int_0^1 \ln\frac{\sqrt{2w^2+1}-w}{\sqrt{2w^2+1}+w} \, \frac{dw}{w^2+1} \tag4 \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{2w^2+1}-w\right)}{w^2+1} - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(w^2+1\right)}{w^2+1} \, dw \\
&= 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \ln\left(\sqrt{\sin^2v+1}-\sin v\right) \,dv & \tag5 \\
&= i \left(\dilog{1+i} - \dilog{1-i}\right) \\
&\qquad + \frac i2 \left(\dilog{\sqrt2\,e^{-i\tfrac{7\pi}{12}}} - \dilog{\sqrt2\,e^{i\tfrac{7\pi}{12}}}\right) \\
&\qquad + \frac i2 \left(\dilog{\sqrt2\,e^{-i\tfrac\pi{12}}} - \dilog{\sqrt2\,e^{i\tfrac\pi{12}}}\right) & \tag6 \\
&= -2 \Im \dilog{1+i} - \Im \dilog{-\sqrt2\,e^{i\tfrac{5\pi}{12}}} - \Im \dilog{\sqrt2\,e^{-i\tfrac\pi{12}}} \tag7
\end{align*}$$

Hence

$$\boxed{I = \frac\pi3+3-\frac{7\sqrt3}4 - \Im \left(2\dilog{1+i} + \dilog{-\sqrt2\,e^{i\tfrac{5\pi}{12}}} + \dilog{\sqrt2\,e^{-i\tfrac\pi{12}}}\right)}$$

---

- $(1)$ Substitute $y=\dfrac{x-1}{x-3}$
- $(2)$ Integrate by parts
- $(3)$ Substitute $z=\sqrt y$ and $z=\sqrt{1-2y}$ in the respective integrals
- $(4)$ Substitute $w=\dfrac z{\sqrt{1-2z^2}}$
- $(5)$ Substitute $w=\tan v$
- $(6)$ See the antiderivative [per W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+ln%28sqrt%28sin%5E2v%2B1%29-sinv%29)
- $(7)$ $\dilog{\overline z}=\overline{\dilog z}$ and $\Im z=\dfrac{z-\overline z}{2i}$