# How to find the probability $P\{X_1 + X_2 \leq X_3\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be three independent and mutually identically distributed random variable with uniform distribution on closed interval [0,1]. What is the probability $P\{X_1 + X_2 \leq X_3\}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146450/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may also do it by convolution of pdfs.

Suppose the random variable $Z=X_1+X_2$, then by convolution, the pdf of $Z$ is:

\begin{align*}
  f(z) &= \left\{\begin{matrix}
 z & 0\le z < 1\\ 
2-z & 1\le z < 2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align*}

Hence

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(Z<X_3\right) &= \int_0^1\, \int_0^{x_3} z\, dz\, dx_3 \\
  &= \frac{1}{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi, read about convolution in [this book](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/amsbook.mac.pdf), has several good problems.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  What is the volume of the region in $\mathbb R^3$ satisfying $0 \le x \le 1$, $0 \le y \le 1$, $x+y \le z \le 1$?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\left.\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{z\ >\ x\ +\ y}}
=\left.\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x + y}^{1}\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{x\ +\ y\ <\ 1}
\\[3mm]&=\left.\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x - y}\,\dd y\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{y\ <\ 1\ -\ x}
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x}\pars{1 - x - y}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{2} - {\pars{1 - x}^{2} \over 2}}\,\dd x
=\half\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}\,\dd x = \color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 6}}
\end{align}

Comment: Why did you use color?