# how to calculate P(Z>X+Y) where X,Y,Z∼U(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I saw the following question [Find $ P(Z>X+Y)$ where $X,Y,Z \sim U(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/find-pzxy-where-x-y-z-sim-u0-1) which asks a specific question about the derivation of P(Z>X+Y). I would like to know how to actually solve the underlying problem with a worked through answer, either with calculus or the more geometric approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the probability mass uniformly distributed across the unit cube. The plane $X+Y=Z$ passes through its vertices $(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,0)$ and thus cuts off a tetrahedron with height 1 and base area $1/2$. Checking the direction of the inequality, this tetrahedron represents the probability you want, which is therefore $1*1/2*1/3=1/6$.