# Compute $P(X+Y>Z)$ where $X, Y$ and $Z$ are independent, uniform random variables in the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I know that if $W=X+Y$ then 
$$f_{W}(t) = t\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(t)+(2-t)\mathbf{1}_{(1,2]}(t).$$
Thus, we want to find $P(W>Z)=P(W-Z>0).$  Using Bayes Theorem we get that 
$$P(W-Z>0) = P(W-Z>0|W\leq 1)P(W\leq 1)+P(W-Z>0|W> 1)P(W> 1)$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{w} dz \cdot P(W\leq 1)+P(Z\leq 1)P(W>1)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+1\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Is this calculation correct?

**Edit**

Based on the suggestion made in the comment we consider the following:

$$P(W>Z)=\int_{0}^{2}P(Z<w)f_{W}(w)dw$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}w^2\cdot dw+\int_{1}^{2}(2-w)\cdot dw=\frac{1}{3}+2-\frac{3}{2}=5/6.$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: No this is not correct.  To compute probabilities, you need to condition on _convenient things_.  It is not convenient to condition on the event  $\{W\leq 1\}$ because it is not precise enough (there are too many scenarios to consider, each depending on the specific value of $W$ given that $W\leq 1$).  So, why not make life _easy_ and condition on all possible values of $W$?  $$P[Z<W] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P[Z<W|W=w]f_W(w)dw=\int_{0}^{2} P[Z<W|W=w]f_W(w)dw$$

Comment: @Michael I made an edit. Is this correct now?

Comment: Yes that looks good now. If you want, you can write that answer yourself in the answer field below and give it  "best answer" (which is good practice when solving a problem based on hints).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $ P(Z&gt;X+Y)$ where $X,Y,Z \sim U(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/find-pzxy-where-x-y-z-sim-u0-1)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Irwin–Hall distribution

$$W = X + Y,\qquad f_W(w)= w 1_{(0,1]}(w) + (2 - w)1_{(1,2)}(w)$$

then you get

$$
\begin{align}
P(W > Z) 
  &= P(W > Z\mid W > 1)P(W > 1)+ P(W > Z, W \leq 1) \\
  &= 1 \cdot \int_1^2(2-w)dw + 
     \int_0^1\int_0^wwdzdw \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

as [Doug M](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3024341/253239) points out. You forgot a $w$ and $dw$ in $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{w} dz$.

Answer (score 0):

$x+y > z\\
0\le z \le 1$

Either $x +y > 1$ and we can ignore $z$ or $x+y\le 1$ and $z < x+y$

$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{x+y} dz\ dy\ dx + \int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{1} dy\ dx\\
\frac 13 + \frac 12$