# Probability of $X+Y>Z$ for i.i.d. random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, problem-solving

$X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d. $\operatorname{U}(0,1)$ random variables. What is the probability that $X+Y>Z$?

Not sure how to solve this problem, does this has anything to do with volume of simplex?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146450/321264

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, it's the volume of the part of the cube $[0,1]^3$ for which $z < x + y$. If you draw the picture you will see the region in question is indeed a cube with a simplex carved out. So your task is to find the volume of this simplex, and your answer will be $1$ minus this volume.

Answer (score 0):

According to your cell comments, I think it is the volume
$$1-\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}(1-x-y)dydx=1-\int_0^1[y-xy-\frac{1}{2}y^2]_0^{1-x}dx$$
$$=1-\int_0^1(\frac{1}{2}-x+\frac{1}{2}x^2)dx=1-[\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3]_0^1$$
$$=1-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6})=1-\frac{1}{6}$$
$$=\frac{5}{6}$$